# Merge native dlls into exe

Tags: windows

Is it possible to merge multiple native dlls into an exe?

Yes, I'm aware that his is easily possible with .NET/Mono/Managed dlls, but can I do the same with native ones? I've found [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/), but as it seems it only can pack the files, not merge them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Link Libraries are designed to be used externally. While it should theoretically be possible to repackage the functions they contain, realistically, the best you can do reliably is to pack everything into a self-extracting archive that will extract the executable and its DLLs into a temp folder, then run the executable.

If you can get a hold of the source code, you can probably compile it with minimal changes to a static library (.lib) that could be linked with the program that needs the DLLs, rather than the DLLs being external.

Comment: The conclusion in this answer is misleading. Clearly there is no reason why merging a few native DLLs to a native EXE is impossible or fundamentally limited. Writing and adding a custom EXE + DLL loader (which loads these from the same file, performs relocations etc.) to the beginning of the EXE would solve this problem. (However, it may still be possible that there isn't or answerers don't know of a ready-made tool for it which works with UPX.)

Comment: Of course, it's impossible to merge a DLL to multiple EXE files using it, and still get both the size and the memory savings. However, the OP doesn't seem to care about file sizes or using extra memory. One possible use case is that the .exe is small (<10 KiB) and the DLL is large (>1 MiB). If the merged EXE is not much larger than the original DLL, then it's a good enough solution.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have an executable that statically imports from a DLL, you could use the [pefrmdllembed](https://osdn.net/projects/pefrm-units/) tool using the "-impinj" commandline option. It can merge native DLL files into native EXE files (of the same architecture) while resolving the imports.

**Example:** pefrmdllembed.exe -impinj myapp.exe ogg.dll myapp_injected.exe

It will work with most DLLs. Be careful about special NT loader features such as static TLS; unsupported under 64bit and might not produce good results under 32bit.

Comment: Thank you for the application. It works great for my project. Unfortunately it is not compatible with UPX. Nor compression before, nor compression after packing the files into single executable.